# auto fill a concatenated formula of several rows with a repeating pattern

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, auto-form-fill

When I try to use the fill option, or double click bottom right corner of 1st cell with the formula, instead of grabbing the next set of 10 rows, it starts with row 2.

Example formula: concatenates the first 10 rows using ; as the delimiter.

```
=CONCATENATE(TRIM(A1),";",TRIM(A2),";",TRIM(A3),";",TRIM(A4),";",TRIM(A5),";",TRIM(A6),";",TRIM(A7),";",TRIM(A8),";",TRIM(A9),";",TRIM(A10),";")
```

Next set should be the next 10 rows (A11 - A20) and so on.

Thank you,

Comment: What version do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Use TEXTJOIN with INDEX and some math to do the range change:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,TRIM(INDEX(A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*10+1):INDEX(A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*10+10)))
```

Put that in the first cell and drag down as far as you want.

It will now move the reference range by 10 cells for every row it is dragged down.

TEXTJOIN will put the delimiter in between each cell.

Comment: Thank you, perfect!!